# Group by issue in Hive

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, aggregate, hiveql

I have table having three field `Tab1(user_id,flag1,flag2)`. sample data:

```
user_id    Flag1     Flag2
10001       0          1 
10001       1          0
10001       0          1
10002       1          0
10002       0          1
```

How to get output as:

```
User_id.   Flag1.     Flag2
10001       1         1
10002       1         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use max() and group by user_id:

```
select user_id, max(flag1) as flag1, max(flag2) as flag2
  from Tab1
 group by user_id;
```